Apple Mail Forwarding Messages To Other Accounts Without Rules To Do So
Apple Mail on my Mini is set up with a handful of email accounts from various providers. When I use the webmail for these accounts everything is normal. I have checked all of these accounts for any forwarding rules I (or anyone) might have set up and have found none that would do what is happening and I deleted the few rules on these accounts that I had created.
When I use Apple Mail to access these accounts, emails to specific accounts get redirected to other accounts. I have removed all of my email accounts from the app on my devices other than the Mini. I have unchecked all of the Rules I had set up in the Apple Mail app, none of which should have been doing what's happening. The problem persists.
I assume (hope) this is a file corruption somewhere. It's not just moving the messages to unwanted folders, it's actually sending them to other accounts. Can I just reinstall Mail to stop this? Is there a specific file I can delete that will repopulate freshly to stop this? What do I need to backup before trying to fix whatever is happening with Mail, if I otherwise want to preserve all my data? Thanks.

I’m not sure I understand the question. What exactly do you mean when you say that mail is forwarded to other accounts? Does it go to the wrong recipient, or is it sent from the wrong outgoing mail server? Did you have the same problem with your other devices, or only this one? Has Mail ever worked the way you expect, and if so, what did you change just before it stopped working?

This forwarded email, if you look at its headers, what do you see?

@LincDavis Emails to me@outlook.com will be redirected to me@icloud.com; emails to mypurchases@rarehost.com will be redirected to random@gmail.com. It's two specific accounts this is happening with, different email hosts and being sent to different email hosts. It's weird. I was encountering the problem on all Apple Devices I was signed into Mail with, but the problem does not exist when just using webmail for the accounts & persists with Apple Mail with only the Mini having access to my email accounts for Apple Mail. Mail worked normally for me until about a week ago when this began.

@Marc Wilson - I don't notice anything odd in the headers but can't claim enormous familiarity with email headers. The messages are being sent to the correct accounts, but when Apple Mail gets involved wind up in inboxes of different hosts. If I just check my outlook with their app or the webmail, everything has arrived, if I access my account with the Apple Mail app, newish emails somehow get forwarded to iCloud. Same is happening with otherhost to a specific gmail account. No rules set up in Apple Mail, in iCloud, in Outlook, in Gmail, in Etc, that should be doing this. It's very strange.

So I take it we're talking about incoming mail. Is that right? A message to your address A is received at address B. Does this also happen when you send yourself a test message to address A? In the Connection Doctor window, are all accounts showing green?

@LincDavis yes, as far as I know, this is only happening with incoming mail. Message from Account A will be properly received by Account B but when Apple Mail gets into the mix the message will somehow be redirected to Account C. Yes, this has happened with the test emails I've sent, too. All Accounts appear to be functioning normally and do function normally (via webmail) as long as I don't open Apple Mail.

From the way you describe it, I see no way this can be anything other than (1) a Mail rule, or (2) some third-party Mail extension or plugin. I suggest that you first disable all Mail rules, regardless of whether you think they're involved, and test. If the problem persists, follow the instructions here to disable Mail extensions: https://support.apple.com/guide/mail/use-mail-extensions-mlhla9a93cd5/mac

@LincDavis Yes, that was my first assumption, an errant rule. I disabled all rules both in the app and the few set up on the accounts themselves and the problem persists so my assumption now is that there's some corrupt file with rules making Apple Mail do this. But I don't know what that file would be.

And there are no extensions or plugins?
